# Laravel 4 Using HybridAuth: Facebook Provider Issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, hybridauth

Laravel noob here.

I'm getting a response "**Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id.**". I believe I followed [this example](http://www.mrcasual.com/on/coding/laravel4-package-management-with-composer/) correctly. 

 
1. My Website with Facebook Login is set to http://localhost.com 
2. HybridAuth config. Base url is set to http://localhost.com/laravel4/public/social/auth/ 
3. I tried running samples from HybridAuth on the same server, same facebook app id and app secrete; all seems to work okay except when using Laravel framework. 
4. Ran updates (Laravel 4 and HybridAuth). 
I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Here is how to support all providers

http://stackoverflow.com/a/20000638/1154919

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a trailing slash in the `base_url` variable of your `hybridauth` config? Removing it fixed the problem on my end.

```
# app/config/hybridauth.php
return array(
    "base_url"   => "http://your.site.com/social/auth",
    ...
);
```

Comment: I tried that. I'm experiencing a very similar issue: http://localhost.xxxxx:8080/social/auth?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1400105601 . It just sits there and laughs at me. Nothing happens. I've posted more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665943/mamp-laravel-php-hybridauth-redirect-fail